# Copying a visual without static reference

Tags: excel, vba

My excel has simple code that copies a range number of times based on value in the cell. However that range contains a visual (filled radar) and when that visual is copied the cell reference stays the same (values in the range H50:h60) so the visual looks the same every time it is copied and visual needs to be manually adjusted to have values in line with it's cells.

```
Sub CopyMulti()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Pass"

    Range("A46:s63").Copy Range("a64").Resize(18 * Range("q7").Value)
    Range("a64").Resize(18 * Range("q7").Value).RowHeight = Range("a46").RowHeight

    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Pass"
End Sub
```

I want the visual to reference cells in newly copied lines.
So instead every visual to have values for the range H50:h60, when i run the macro I need it to reference H68:h78, then the second one H86:h96 etc. It doesn't need to be a macro, but the issue is that excel automatically adds $ when range is added to visual so I get $H$50:$h$60.

Comment: If you want to perform the code multiple times, you can use a loop: https://www.excelfunctions.net/vba-loops.html

Comment: @AlexdeJong thanks, but my code is doing what I need. However my problem is the chart, that it always retains the same values and I want it to take the new values as explained in my post